# showing subversion files instead of website

Tags: php, svn, web, web-hosting, dreamhost

Hey I recently bought a domain and server at dreamhost.
I created a subversion so that I can better manage my files and versions.
When I create a folder and a file say index.php everything works fine and the code runs great.

However once I do a checkout of the subversion in that folder (or even into a new folder) and add files from the repository to it, the site doesn't show. Instead I just see the subversion name and revision and the files and if I click on a file it downloads it.

Why isn't the site actually running? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that index.php was not changed?

Comment: I'm certain. It's just so weird. If I add a file manually everything works fine but if I use svn it's not working.

Comment: Please write your root directory structure so i can help you

Comment: domain_name.com/folder_name as simple as that

Comment: When you use this url see a error? this error code is 433 or ...?

Comment: No there's no error, like I said it shows me the files in the repository instead of the website itself.

Comment: Just for some added clarification I will ask a couple of questions. 1) "However once I do a checkout of the subversion in that folder and add files from the repository to it, the site doesn't show". Now when you say you did a checkout, did you do a checkout on the server or your local computer? 2) On your server, do you have the repository hosted on the server, and do you have a separate checkout **on** the server to view the files? 3) Based on reading the comments it sounds like you're just accessing the URL to the repository, which it's doing as it's intended and showing you the contents of

Comment: the repository (and thus, clicking an item downloads it). Not too familiar with dreamhost off the top of my head, but are you using apache or something of the sort? You would have to configure the server to point to a specific directory for "web access" so to speak. Like if on your server you had a folder called "www" and then you did a _checkout_ of your repository into this directory (not directly accessing the repo itself), the index.php (or whatever other) files will show up in this directory. But this all depends on the config of your server.

Comment: 1. I did a checkout on both, tried doing first on the server and then on the computer, and tried the other way around. Once the checkout on the server is in place it no longer acts as a website but as a repository. 2) I created the repository using dreamhost subversion and did a checkout on the server in the folder I wanted. 3) I agree with what you think, I bought a "shared" server on dreamhost. I have access to my folder on it and php and everything works fine there when I create new files and upload them even in different folders. However once I do checkout in a folder it now longer works.

Comment: And I can't configure the php or the apache by myself I didn't install them and I don't think I have access. Thanks.

Comment: Hard to diagnose without more details... Try to edit your question writing down exactly each command you write, with full paths. I sense what happens is that when you check-out files, something gets renamed and Apache gets confused. You can also try asking on discussion.dreamhost.com